# How can I call methods of class without initializing their objects?

Tags: java, class, object

For example I have

```
class A{
    ...
    void function()
    {

    } 

}

class B{
    ...
    void function2()
    {

    } 

}

class C{
    ...
    void function3()
    {

    } 

}

class myClass{
    ...
}
```

Can I use the `function()`, `function2()`, and `function3()` methods in the `myClass` class without creating an object of class `A`, `B`, or `C`?

Comment: Please reformulate this question by posting some code, ideally, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), instead of using phrases detailing your code; this is unreadable and unclear. I doubt anyone will try to understand your question in its current state.

Comment: still I cannot reach them??

Answer (score 4):

Now you have *instance* methods. So you need instances of A, B and C in order to call the methods:

```
new A().function();
```

If you declare the methods with the static modifier, i.e.

```
public static void function() { /* ... */ }
```

then you can call them without creating instances:

```
A.function();
```

Comment: Sorry but  new A() doesnt mean creating an object??

Comment: @hiii yes it does and this is the way OO-language work. Try to avoid using `static` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First I made the methods static then from another class I called them as classNameThatHasTheStaticMethod.StaticMethodName()